# what are the benefits and harms of having light font on saturated colored background?

Tags: gui-design, color

the example could be seen from the new google calendar

- it was white font
- on a saturated color box (colorful, very 'rich' in colors', 'bright', or im not sure what's the technical way of describing this)

what are the benefits and harms of this because it appear to be very very hard to see the font when this is done

p.s. hello this is **not** duplicate cos 'bright' colors arent dark, and also there's no answer to google calendar, so it shoulnt be 'duplicate'

Answer (score 0):

Their use of bright colors is based on their material design guidelines. Google argues that as long as the contrast is high enough, text should be  readable for anyone. More specifically, a contrast ratio of 4.5:1 is required for normal text. Refer to the [color](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#) part of their guidelines to learn more about it.

As for the benefits of this, they state the following:

> Deliberate color choices, edge-to-edge imagery, large-scale typography, and intentional white space create a bold and graphic interface that immerse the user in the experience. An emphasis on user actions makes core functionality immediately apparent and provides waypoints for the user.

Comment: don't they recommend black text for those 'saturated' or 'bright' backgrounds?